# Is it correct to use div tag inside anchor tag?

Tags: html, jsp-tags

I have used the following piece of code where I have used div tag inside anchor tag. The code is working fine but I am not sure if this is the correct format. Is it correct to use div inside anchor tag ?

```
<a class="discount-popup" href="#" id="WC_Link_ProductDiscount_1_<c:out value="${discountCounter.count}"/>">
    <div id="view_offer" style="display: block;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<u style="color: #000000;"><c:out value="View offer details" escapeXml="true" /></u>
    </div>
    <div id="offer_details" style="display: none;">
        <c:out value="${calculationCodeDBs[0].longDescriptionString}" escapeXml="false" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you fix your post, I don't see any code. Of course you can use a div inside of an anchor tag, but the A tag by default is an inline element. So you will want to declare it as a inline block and give it defined hight and width. Otherwise it will shrink to the line hight. Which could be a problem.

Comment: You can post the output of the JSP in a HTML validator and see..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: wrong code , check https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Wrong code? did you see the special markup of some framework?

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 you can. In previous versions of HTML you can't. To make this code valid you need to set the correct doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

With this doctype the browser identifies HTML5 page. Put it before `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its fine to you use DIV elements inside an anchor tag, but you will need to setup your CSS correctly for each one (height, width, display, etc), otherwise, the height will revert to the line height by default.

Hope this helps.